# How to replace files in PPA after unsuccessful build?

Tags: ppa, compiling, packaging, upload

I uploaded a package to my PPA, but the build failed. I made some corrections to the dependencies list and tried to upload the corrected file. It was rejected with this message:

> Rejected: File -1.tar.gz already exists in ,
>   but uploaded version has different contents. See more information
>   about this error in https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/UploadErrors.
>   Files specified in DSC are broken or missing, skipping package unpack
>   verification.

I deleted the package from the PPA, and now it is absent in the list on the PPA webpage, but still I receive
the same e-mail when trying to upload the new archive.

So how is it supposed to be done correctly, when the build fails because of missing dependencies, and the packager corrects the dependencies list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid confusion, Launchpad *never* allows different uploads under the (exact) same version number. You can upload previously uploaded packages, only if they are *exactly* the same, with the `dput -f` option. See [this answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+faq/990) and [this one](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/135944) on Launchpad.

If you delete a package from Launchpad, it is deleted according a procedure as described [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Deleting). Launchpad still keeps a checksum however of the deleted files to prevent future (version-) conflicting uploads.

The bottom line is that you will have to upload under an increased version number. Not that it helps for now, but you can prevent errors by first try building locally.

Comment: @Josh Thanks, I'll try to find out if it still exists somewhere. I will remove the link for now,